# How to find exact location of a word in list of lists in python(find_word_horizontal)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists:

```
my_list=[['d','c','d','o','g','q'],
            ['c','c','u','c','m','w'],
            ['x','c','c','a','t','t'],
            ['t','c','e','t','k','e']]

word='cat'
```

I want to find the location of the word[0] and return it as a list:
word[0]='c', so my function should return this:

```
[2,2]...
```

If my word is `'dog'`, My function would return:

```
[0,2]...
```

I have the following code bu it doesn't work.

```
def find_word_horizontal(my_list, word):
    r=[]
    for row in my_list:
        x = "".join(row)
        s=x.find(word)
        if s != -1:
            a=my_list.index(row)
            r.append(a)
            b=x.index(word[0])
            r.append(b)
    return r
```

returns: [2,1] for 'cat' instead [2,2] and [0,1] for  'dog' instead [0,2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find_word_horizontal(my_list, word):
    r=[]
    for row in my_list:
        x = "".join(row)
        s=x.find(word)
        if s != -1:
            a=my_list.index(row)
            r.append(a)
            b=x.index(word)
            r.append(b)
    return r
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem in your code is on this line:

```
b=x.index(word[0])
```

it should be:

```
b=x.index(word)
```